# Python decorators with *args and **kwargs failing to execute with error message about too many positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Any article, tutorial, etc. I have read on writing decorators in Python has pointed me to using *args and **kwargs to write decorators which can be applied to any function and / or method (including [this great introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)).

However I now have the following code:

```
def format_result(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # do something with result
        return result

    return func_wrapper
```

Which I then use as follows:

```
class CategoryList(BaseResource):
    '''List or create categories'''

    @format_result
    def get(self):
        '''Create a new category'''
        return {'id': 1, 'name': 'Test Category'}
```

When using this code in my application, I always receive the following error message:

```
File "...\__init__.py", line 66, in func_wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Am I doing something wrong? If relevant, my python -V is "Python 3.5.1".

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You need to show the code where you try to use `get`, as well as the complete error traceback (not just the last part)

Answer (score 0):

It may because you are trying to wrap a method of a class with the decorator. The requirements for writing decorators which work on methods of a class are a bit different, even worse if you need the one decorator which can work on both normal functions and methods of a class.

You are much better off using a package which helps you to implement the decorator rather than trying to do it yourself, as there are many gotchas if trying to do it yourself.

I would suggest you look at the `wrapt` package. See:

- http://wrapt.readthedocs.io

Is worthwhile also reading:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/p/decorators-and-monkey-patching.html

if you believe hand rolled decorators are always going to work.

As noted above, otherwise provide the code where `get()` is being called. If this call is being down in some fancy way, that could be causing an issue.

Comment: I don't think being a method is the problem in the questioner's case. It certainly *can* be an issue, but decorators generally work fine as long as they're returning a function (rather than some other kind of callable) and the wrapper function does not modify the positional arguments in a way that breaks `self`.